# CSS flexbox single column list item issues

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to display a list of items in a single column. The list is long so I want it to scroll if they all don't fit.

On all browsers right and left margin not appearing

On **chrome**: The issue is that if the window becomes smaller, the top items start to disappear and hide as the window shrinks. Also first item top margin missing.

[image: chrome]

On **IE11** sometimes the rows doesn't take 100% but shrinks to the content width. If I resize the IE window it displays properly.

[image: ie11]

**Edit**:

After removing `justify-content: center;` it solved the vertical issue on chrome, but suddenly no bottom margin appears on **IE11**

[image: ie11 edit]

This is the CSS

```
body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0pt;
 padding: 0pt;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: #e6e6fa;
}

div.list {
 max-height: 80%;
 width: 60%;
 margin: 0pt;
 padding: 0pt;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 flex-direction: column;
 overflow-y: auto;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 background-color: red;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

div.list .row {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 4pt 12pt 4pt 12pt;
 padding: 0pt;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex: 0 0 auto;
 box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000000;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

div.list .row .content {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0pt;
 padding: 0pt;
 flex: 0 0 auto;
 direction: rtl;
 text-align: right;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="list">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="content" style="color:#2b8ACA">title</div>
    <div class="content">description</div>
    <div class="content" style="color:#BABABA">date</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You're centering the list items vertically...with `justify-content: center;` I would assume you don't want that. I'd suggest removing it. That should take care of your first issue.

Comment: Thanks, it partially solved the vertical issue. But after removing the line on IE11 - no bottom margin is visible. Appears perfect on chrome

Comment: IE11 is quite as good a support for flexbox yet. - See the Known Issues at http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox